# Why does Drop glue sometimes not run?

Tags: rust

I've had this happen in other circumstances, but not repeatably.

Basically, sometimes when you have a `*mut Foo`, and you turn it into a `Foo` using `ptr::read()`, sometimes your drop glue doesn't seem to run.

Here's a repeatable example that runs on playpen without using FFI (which is the main reason you'd promote a raw pointer back into an object): http://is.gd/X6vdAK

```
use std::ptr::read;
use std::mem::forget;

#[repr(C)]
struct Foo {
  id: i32,
  dispose:Option<Box<Fn(Foo) + 'static>> //'
}

impl Foo {
  pub fn new(id:i32) -> Foo {
    return Foo {
        id: id,
        dispose: None
    };
  }
  pub fn release(mut self) {
    if self.dispose.is_some() {
      self.dispose.take().unwrap()(self);
    }
  }
}

impl Drop for Foo {
  fn drop(&mut self) {
    println!("Discarding a foo with dispose of {:?}", self.dispose.is_some());
  }
}

#[repr(C)]
struct Goblin {
  foo:Foo,
  angry: bool,
  friends: i32
}

#[repr(C)]
struct Bat {
  foo:Foo,
  hungry: bool
}

#[repr(C)]
struct Dragon {
  foo:Foo,
  lairs: i32
}

trait IsFoo {
  fn foo(&mut self) -> &mut Foo; 
  fn as_foo<T: IsFoo>(mut self) -> Foo where Self: Sized {
    let ptr:*const Foo = self.foo() as *mut Foo;
    {
        self.foo().dispose = Some(Box::new(|&:foo:Foo| {
          println!("Incoming release for id {}", foo.id);
          unsafe {
            let tmp = &foo as *const Foo as *const T; // Avoid ICE. :(
            let mut instance:T = read::<T>(tmp);
            println!("Dropping instance with id: {}", instance.foo().id);
            drop(instance);
          }
        }));
    }
    unsafe { 
        let rtn = read(ptr);
        forget(self);
        return rtn;
    }
  }
}
impl IsFoo for Bat { fn foo(&mut self) -> &mut Foo { return &mut self.foo; } }
impl IsFoo for Goblin { fn foo(&mut self) -> &mut Foo { return &mut self.foo; } }
impl IsFoo for Dragon { fn foo(&mut self) -> &mut Foo { return &mut self.foo; } }

// Test drops work
impl Drop for Bat { fn drop(&mut self) { println!("Dropped a Bat"); } }
impl Drop for Goblin { fn drop(&mut self) { println!("Dropped a Goblin....!"); } }
impl Drop for Dragon { fn drop(&mut self) { println!("Dropped a Dragon"); } }

fn main() {
  {
    // Generic collection
    let monsters:Vec<Foo> = vec!(
      Bat { foo: Foo::new(1), hungry: true }.as_foo::<Bat>(),
      Goblin { foo: Foo::new(2), angry: true, friends: 100 }.as_foo::<Goblin>(),
      Dragon { foo: Foo::new(3), lairs: 33 }.as_foo::<Dragon>()
    );

    println!("Vector exists without dropping contents");

    // Cleanup
    for m in monsters.into_iter() { 
      println!("Dropping an instance: {}", m.id);
      m.release(); 
    }
  }
}
```

The output here is:

```
Vector exists without dropping contents
Dropping an instance: 1
Incoming release for id 1
Dropping instance with id: 1
Discarding a foo with dispose of false
Dropping an instance: 2
Incoming release for id 2
Dropping instance with id: 2
Discarding a foo with dispose of false
Dropping an instance: 3
Incoming release for id 3
Dropping instance with id: 3
Discarding a foo with dispose of false
```

i.e. Although I'm converting the reference `*mut Foo` into a `T` in the closure, the drop glue for `Goblin`, `Dragon` & `Bat` doesn't run.

If you tweak the code slightly, for example http://is.gd/mRzj8H, you can get these (or some of these) to run:

```
Vector exists without dropping contents
Dropping an instance: 1
Dropped a Bat
Dropping an instance: 2 <--- WTF, the others work but this one doesn't?
Dropping an instance: 3
Dropped a Dragon
```

Am I seeing the artifacts of some kind of race condition here, or something more complex?

Comment: That title ... is interestn

Comment: @Coffee ? Drop glue is what it's called isn't it? ie. When drop is run...

Comment: In this case I think one would just call the drop implementation "a destructor", "drop glue" usually refers to the auto-generated compiler internals that manage calling the user-defined destructors appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try compiling your program with different optimization levels. (There's a drop-down for this on the Rust playpen; the default there is `-O2`.) You'll see that the output is not consistent. In this case, you're invoking undefined behaviour.

When you add items to the `Vec`, you create objects like `Bat` that contain a `Foo`, then you add just the `Foo` in the `Vec`. **The `Bat` no longer exists.** `IsFoo::as_foo` takes the `Bat` by value, which means it takes ownership of it. The `Bat` is effectively dropped at the end of `as_foo`, but you suppressed the drop glue by calling `forget`.

In your "dispose" lambda, you try to get a `Bat` back by casting a pointer to `Foo` to a pointer to `Bat`. This is **undefined behaviour**, because the vector contains just the `Foo`, not the whole `Bat`.  Remember, the `Bat` was destroyed when leaving `IsFoo::as_foo`.

With `-O2` and `-O3`, it's possible that the program isn't creating a `Vec` at all, and the `Bat`, `Dragon` and `Goblin` values are still intact on the stack. However, `Goblin` doesn't have `#[repr(C)]`, while the other two do, so that may be why the destructor didn't run on that one only.

Comment: edit: Nevermind, I see. Moving it into as_foo moves it onto the stack for as_foo and out of main's stack, which is lost at the end of as_foo. The solution is to box the values so they remain on the heap until collected.

Comment: Correct. You probably want a `Vec<Box<IsFoo>>`.

Answer (score 0):

In Rust 1.0 `Drop` is not supported on `#[repr(C)]` types.

This is because `Drop` adds a hidden flag to the structure and runs the destructor only if that flag is set.

This is a known wart in the language and in the future it may be changed by tracking the drop flag out of band.

There's `#[unsafe_no_drop_flag]` that removes the `Drop` flag, but then Rust doesn't guarantee how many times the destructor will be called (your destructor must run be able to safely on an object that has already been destroyed).